# Getting Location Header Python Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm trying to submit a payment to a site and I need to get a returned Location header. I have tried `allow_redirects=False` but I'm not getting the header returned. Most of the posts are with a session so I have tried both the session and just requests.

Returned Headers:
`{'Allow': 'HEAD, GET', 'Content-Length': '0', 'Server': '', 'Expires': 'Wed, 13 Apr 2022 01:34:32 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0, no-cache, no-store', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Date': 'Wed, 13 Apr 2022 01:34:32 GMT', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Server-Timing': 'cdn-cache; desc=MISS, edge; dur=11, origin; dur=7', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains'}`

Chrome Headers:

```
cache-control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
content-length: 0
date: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 00:48:21 GMT
expires: Wed, 13 Apr 2022 00:48:21 GMT
location: https://www.bigw.com.au/checkout/webpay/success?dts_reference=5000000315110950
pragma: no-cache
server
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=MISS
server-timing: edge; dur=11
server-timing: origin; dur=197
set-cookie: AKA_A2=A; expires=Wed, 13-Apr-2022 01:48:21 GMT; path=/; domain=payments.woolworths.com.au; secure; HttpOnly
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
```

My Code:

```
headers = {
                                    'authority': 'iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au',
                                    'method': 'POST',
                                    'path': '/WOWPaymentService/webservice/continueSecureData',
                                    'scheme': 'https',
                                    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                                    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9',
                                    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
                                    'content-length': '147',
                                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                                    'dnt': '1',
                                    'origin': 'https://iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au',
                                    'referer': link_full,
                                    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"',
                                    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
                                    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
                                    'sec-fetch-dest': 'iframe',
                                    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
                                    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
                                    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
                                    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
                                    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.88 Safari/537.36'
                                }
                                payload = {
                                    'card_number': '4007000000027',
                                    'exp_month': '04',
                                    'exp_year': '2023',
                                    'cv2_number': '456',
                                    'HPS_SessionID': str(link),
                                    'issue_number': '',
                                    'action': 'confirm'
                                }
                                r = requests.post("https://iframe.payments.woolworths.com.au/WOWPaymentService/webservice/continueSecureData", allow_redirects=True, verify=False, json=payload, headers=headers, timeout=10)
                                print(r.url)
                                print(r.headers)
```

Sorry, it's tabbed over

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation advises you to consult `r.history`
rather than `r.url`.

https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history

---

Also, when you had `allow_redirects=False`,
I assume you verified that `r.status` was 301 or 302?
You should be able to chase the redirect at app level.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
re= requests.get(f"https://rofan.com",allow_redirects=False, timeout=5)
location = (re.headers['Location'])
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?